# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "" Edit Text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, double, numberformatexception

I have 6 edit text fields, and I'm trying to input them into a sqlite database and I'm trying to parse 5 of them into doubles, but it throws that error and I can not figure out what to do.
I've tried to use `valueOf(String)` and parsing, but neither seem to work.

I've used Long's and Integers as well, and have come to the same issue as well

Here's the code:

```
public class EditClass extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText name, exam, quiz, assignment, participation, lab;
String iName, sExam, sQuiz, sAss, sPart, sLab ;
double iExam, iQuiz, iLab, iAss, iPart;
FloatingActionButton fab;
Database database;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_class);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.class_name);
    exam = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.exam_weight);
    quiz = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.quiz_weight);
    assignment = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.assignment_weight);
    participation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.participation_weight);
    lab = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lab_weight);

    iName = name.getText().toString();
    sExam = exam.getText().toString();
    sQuiz = quiz.getText().toString();
    sAss = assignment.getText().toString();
    sPart = participation.getText().toString();

    ImageView create = new ImageView(this);
    create.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.checkmark));

    fab = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this).setContentView(create).build();
    fab.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_action_lightblue_ztek));
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    addData();
}

public void addData(){
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                /**
                 * Errors with parsing into integer form, comes up with NumberFormatException
                 */
               database.insertData(iName,
                        iExam = Double.valueOf(sExam),
                        iQuiz = Double.valueOf(sQuiz),
                        iLab = Double.valueOf(sLab),
                        iAss = Double.valueOf(sAss),
                        iPart = Double.valueOf(sPart));

                        Toast.makeText(EditClass.this, "Data was Successfully Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch (Exception e){
               String error= e.toString();
                Toast.makeText(EditClass.this, "Data was Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(error);

            }
        }
    });
}}
```

I've now ended up changing the addData method to this, but it comes up as null now, for both the string and doubles.

Here's the method:

```
public void addData(){
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                /**
                 * Errors with parsing into integer form, comes up with NumberFormatException
                 */
               database.insertData(name.getText().toString(),
                        Double.parseDouble(exam.getText().toString()),
                        Double.parseDouble(quiz.getText().toString()),
                        Double.parseDouble(lab.getText().toString()),
                        Double.parseDouble(assignment.getText().toString()),
                     Double.parseDouble(participation.getText().toString()));


                        Toast.makeText(EditClass.this, "Data was Successfully Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }catch (Exception e){
               String error= e.toString();
                Toast.makeText(EditClass.this, "Data was Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                System.out.println(error);

            }



        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your fields contain `double`s only ?

Comment: does your doubles have a comma or a point?

Comment: You have to validate your fields, before call `Double.valueOf` for the fields

Comment: Yes they only contain doubles, and ive tried with integers and longs, as well with the same issue and they have neither commas or points

Answer (score 1):

`onCreate()` only runs once and is currently the only place you call `getText()`. Therefore, the values in `iName`, `sExam`, etc are all the default values you have for those fields - not the current values when your `FloatingActionButton` is clicked.

Instead, move the `iName = name.getText().toString();` etc lines into your `OnClickListener` to get the current values when the button is clicked.

Also note that you cannot use `Double.valueOf()` on an empty field (that's the `NumberFormatException` you are getting) - consider wrapping each call in [TextUtils.isEmpty()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isEmpty(java.lang.CharSequence)) to check to see if there is any value at all.